# Atom Editor - Quickly comment a block with asterisks?

Tags: javascript, comments, atom-editor

I'm using Atom 1.14.2.

If I have, for example, a JavaScript object literal:

```
{
  test: 123
}
```

Is there a quick way to either turn it into **this specific style** of multi line comment:

```
/**
 * {
 *   test: 123
 * }
 */
```

...or at least quickly **add the asterisks**:

```
 * {
 *   test: 123
 * }
```

..?

So, I want to add `*` (space-asterisk-space) before all selected lines.

I've installed [docblockr](https://atom.io/packages/docblockr), which is nice, but I can't see a quick way of doing the above.

Answer (score -2):

U can select multiple lines, then use shortcut **⌘ + /** or **ctrl + /**

Comment: Nope! That adds one or many single line comments (in the case of JavaScript it adds `// `). I asked a specific type of comment.